# Faulty number generator in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, generator, display

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

def numberGenerator():
    window=Tk()
    window.title("Rndom number generator")
    window.geometry('800x360')
    label=Label(window, text="Number generator", font=('arial',20,'bold'),bg="black",fg="white")
    label.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
    label=Label(window, text="", font=('arial',15,'bold'),bg="black",fg="white")
    label.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)

    nwin = Frame(window) 
    nwin.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)

    num1 = StringVar()
    num2 = StringVar()
    num3 = StringVar()
    num4 = StringVar()
    num5 = StringVar()
    num6 = StringVar()

    def GenerateNum():
        r= random.randint(1,9)
        a= random.randint(1,9)
        n= random.randint(1,9)
        d= random.randint(1,9)
        o= random.randint(1,9)
        m= random.randint(1,9)

        num1.set(r)
        num2.set(a)
        num3.set(n)
        num4.set(d)
        num5.set(o)
        num6.set(m)

        print( r, a , n, d, o, m)
        return
```

This gives each letter the ability to be any number from 1 to 9 and it also assigns it to a num which is defined above as a string Variable.

```
    mwin= Frame(window)
    mwin.pack(side=TOP)
    
    txtDisplay=ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable = num1, font=("Arial"), width=4)
    txtDisplay.grid(row=0,column=0)

    txtDisplay=ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable = num2, font=("Arial"), width=4)
    txtDisplay.grid(row=0,column=1)

    txtDisplay=ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable = num3, font=("Arial"), width=4)
    txtDisplay.grid(row=0,column=2)

    txtDisplay=ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable = num4, font=("Arial"), width=4)
    txtDisplay.grid(row=0,column=3)

    txtDisplay=ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable = num5, font=("Arial"), width=4)
    txtDisplay.grid(row=0,column=4)

    txtDisplay=ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable = num6, font=("Arial"), width=4)
    txtDisplay.grid(row=0,column=5)
```

This create the entry boxes in which the random numbers will be generated

```
    owin= Frame(window)
    owin.pack(side=TOP)

    btnGenerate = ttk.Button(owin, text="Number Generator", command = GenerateNum)
    btnGenerate.grid(row=1,column=6)
```

Button triggers the creation of the random numbers

This code works fine by itself but when it is accessed from another window in my program it doesn't display the numbers in the entry boxes.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be creating a new `Tk` window in the function. You should do this once in the application, then use it in every function.

Comment: tkinter program should have only one `Tk()` (for main window) and other windows should be created with `Toplevel()`. So better create `window` (`Tk()` or `Toplevel()`) outside function and send it as parameter to `numberGenerator`. This way you can run it as standalone window using `Tk()` or as window opened from other window using `Toplevel()`

Comment: you could use `list` to keep `StringVars` and random values. And this way you could use `for`-loop to work with values on list, and to generate all `tk.Entry` - so code could be simpler.

Comment: sometimes can help if you assign `StringVar` to correct window - `num1 = StringVar(window)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Tk()` should be used only to create main window. Other (sub)windows should use `Toplevel()`.

You could send to generator correct window as parameter to run it with `Tk()` or `Toplevel()`

I use `if __name__ == '__main__':` to run generator with `Tk()` when script is executed directly.

**generator.py**

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
import random

def number_generator(window):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    window.title("Rndom number generator")
    window.geometry('800x360')
    
    label = tk.Label(window, text="Number generator", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), bg="black", fg="white")
    label.pack(side='top', fill='x')
    
    label = tk.Label(window, text="", font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), bg="black", fg="white")
    label.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

    nwin = tk.Frame(window) 
    nwin.pack(side='left', fill='both')

    # use `for`-loop to create list with all StringVar
    nums = []
    for i in range(6):
        nums.append(tk.StringVar(window))

    def generate_numbers():  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
        for i in range(6):
           nums[i].set(random.randint(1, 9))
        # display values from all StringVars
        print(*[var.get() for var in nums])

    mwin = tk.Frame(window)
    mwin.pack(side='top')
    
    # use `for`-loop to create all Entry
    for i in range(6):
       entry = ttk.Entry(mwin, textvariable=nums[i], font=("Arial"), width=4)
       entry.grid(row=0, column=i)

    owin = tk.Frame(window)
    owin.pack(side='top')

    button = ttk.Button(owin, text="Number Generator", command=generate_numbers)
    button.grid(row=1, column=6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_window = tk.Tk()  # PEP8: spaces around `=`

    number_generator(main_window)

    main_window.mainloop()
```

And now I can import generator to other script and run it with `Toplevel`

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import generator

def open_subwindow():
    subwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    generator.number_generator(subwindow)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    
    b = tk.Button(main_window, text='Open subwindow', command=open_subwindow)
    b.pack()

    main_window.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:**

Sometimes it can be useful to set parent for `StringVar` -
`tk.StringVar(window)` - because `tk.StringVar()` without parent will be assigned to main window instead of subwindow and this can also make problem.

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yes, it worked wonders. Thank you very much, you have just taught me something new!